# How to view the git history of a project and revert to an older commit?

Tags: git

I am new to open source and git. I have been learning git and contributing to a project. I have been assigned the task of looking into its git history at past commits and learning from the code then (since the project has evolved now). 
I know that git stores the entire history of the project. So is there a way to revert to an older version of the project locally. I don't intend to or have rights to revert its remote repo back in time, I just want to revert my local copy to an older commit.

Comment: revert or just checkout?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

gitk shows a graphical history of commits, each with a unique SHA hash indentifier.

You can checkout to an earlier version using git checkout {commit id}. You make Git revert to an earlier version using these commands:

```
# reset the index to the desired tree
git reset 56e05fced

# move the branch pointer back to the previous HEAD
git reset --soft HEAD@{1}

git commit -m "Revert to 56e05fced"

# Update working copy to reflect the new commit
git reset --hard
```

[Revert to a commit by a SHA hash in Git?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1895059/git-revert-to-a-commit-by-sha-hash)

Comment: `git log` or `git log --graph` will show a commit history, too.

Answer (score 0):

sounds like you should use "git reset" instead of "git revert" to delete recent changes and reset to a former commit.

to list previous commits you may use 
git log 
[image: commit ss]

then once you have found the commit you want to revert to, use the first 9 
characters of that commits SHA in the git reset cmd like:
git reset --hard fbcc6aa00