# How to make old commit object to lastest one?

Tags: git, github

This is my Git status.

[image]

Because of some weird reason, `master` and `task-e` branches are broken. They can't be build now.
Only `6f374ed94ad7f04b1f7a2ca2019374bb7785d9e6` commit is valid.
[image]

I would like to make this commit to lastest commit of `master` branch. How do I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not completely clear from your question, but I assume that what you want is to add a new commit whose source code is exactly the same as at the older commit, `6f374ed9`.  (In other words, you want to avoid rewriting history, since obviously `master` and `task-e` have been pushed to GitHub.)  This takes a few steps in git, which are described in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1895095/223092).  To summarize that, firstly make sure that you have no uncommitted changes (i.e. `git status` is clean).  You would then need to do:

```
# Switch to the branch you want to add the commit to:
git checkout master
# (... you can merge the result to the other branch later)

# Move the master branch back to the earlier, good commit, forcing the
# working tree and the index to match:
git reset --hard 6f374ed

# Use git reset --soft to point the master branch back to where it was
# originally, but leave the working tree and index as they were at 6f374ed
git reset --soft HEAD@{1}

# Commit the result:
git commit -m "Reverting state back to 6f374ed9"
```

Then, to update `task-e` as well, you can do:

```
git checkout task-e
git merge master
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use `git reset`, but it would rewrite history that has already been pushed publicly, so it's not advised. I'd use `git revert` : it allows you to revert a commit, ie. it creates a commit that does the opposite of a commit. That way, you can cancel your commits and get back to the state you want, without rewriting history.