# How to bring back changes after a "git reset --hard"

Tags: git, git-reset

I realized that our branch dev is not very stable and reverted some changes to work on debugging them.

```
git checkout dev
git checkout -b staged_dev
git push origin staged_dev
# go back to dev
git checkout dev
git reset 230086bf429307182ed9b35e19ad2581a3a2baf6 # last known stable state of dev
git reset --soft HEAD@{1}
git commit -m "Revert to 230086bf429307182ed9b35e19ad2581a3a2baf6" # this commit SHA = 270329c
git reset --hard
git push origin dev
```

This added a new commit on top of dev : `270329c`

Since then another person has added some safe commits to dev and I have debugged staged_dev and added some commits. How do I undo `270329c` from dev and add the other commits of staged_dev into dev ?

reference stackoverflow question : [Revert to a commit by a SHA hash in Git?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1895059/revert-to-a-commit-by-sha-hash)

Answer (score 1):

`git reflog` should show you where things were so that you can create an old_dev branch from it.

See [reflog, your safety net](http://gitready.com/intermediate/2009/02/09/reflog-your-safety-net.html)

Comment: +1 for calling out attention to `git reflog` - that would be essential if there was confusion about the revision history.  But I think @humble is clear on that; the question is how to manage merging these branches going forward

Comment: I was simply answering the 'exam' question of `how-to-bring-back-changes-after-a-git-reset-hard`, rather than the corollary ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Your simplest choice might be just:

```
git checkout dev
git merge staged_dev
git push origin dev
```

If you're not happy with the resulting history, you could first rebase your revised changes to the tip of the "dev" branch:

```
git checkout staged_dev
git rebase dev
git checkout dev
git merge staged_dev
```

If you want your revised commits in "staged_dev" to take *the same place* in the history as the original 230086 commit, you're going to have to get fancier, and **there is no way to do that without deleting revision history in "dev" that has already been published in "origin"**.  But if that's what you really need, you could do something like:

```
git checkout -b new-dev 230086bf  # point where "dev" diverged
git cherry-pick <first commit you want to include*>..staged_dev
git checkout -t origin/dev
git rebase new-dev
git push origin +dev
```

You may want to announce to everybody that local checkouts they have of "dev" may no longer be in the upstream history.