# Undo some commits after pushing

Tags: git

In simplified form, I have the following git commits history:

```
* aaaaaaa (origin/master, origin/HEAD, master, HEAD)
* bbbbbbb
* ccccccc
*     Merge from ddddddd
|\
| * ddddddd
| * eeeeeee
| * fffffff
| |
* | ggggggg
* | hhhhhhh
* | iiiiiii
* | kkkkkkk
* | mmmmmmm
| | ooooooo
|/
* xxxxxxx
* zzzzzzz
```

I recently realized that there are bad commits in the master branch:

- `ddddddd`
- `eeeeeee`
- `ffffff`

Is it possible undo changes in local repo made to the `ddddddd`, `eeeeeee` and `fffffff` without changing other local and remote commits?

Comment: Did you rebase to make these changes?

Comment: This issue must be solved through http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1895059/revert-to-a-commit-by-sha-hash

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're working in multiple developers environment, you should just do `git revert sha` for each troublesome commit, then push revert commits to remote. Messing with remote master is bad when you're not the only one active developer.

Comment: Thanks I solved this with http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1895059/revert-to-a-commit-by-sha-hash