# Understanding `git reset --hard`

Tags: git

Say I have a Git repo with the following commits to the master, in order: A, B, C, D. I want to roll back the master to the state that it was in following commit A; in other words, discard the changes from B, C and D. I'm pretty sure that `git reset --hard` would do that. But then, I would like to selectively re-apply some of the discarded patches (`git cherry-pick` is what I want for that, right?) So my specific questions are:

1. Does `git reset --hard` remove anything from the commit history? If I reset the master to A, will B, C and D still be hanging around in the repo?
2. Does `git cherry-pick` allow me to do what I described above, or did I misunderstand it?

Comment: If you want to change history from a specific point, have you considered an interactive [rebase](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-rebase)? Alternatively if you'd like to retain history you could [revert](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-revert) the commits you don't want.

Comment: Reverting the commits is a possibility, but I'd like to avoid that if possible, since I have quite a lot of commits.

Answer (score 14):

To understand `git reset` properly you need all these bits of information:

- The commits themselves exist, in a sense, outside of any branch names.

  When you make a commit, Git assigns it a unique hash ID.  The new commit you make stores inside it the hash ID of whatever commit was your current commit at the time you made it.  We can use these hash IDs to chain the commits together:

  ```
  A <-B <-C <-D
  ```

  We say that each commit *points to* the previous commit.  (Since there was no commit before `A`, it doesn't point anywhere.  If there *is* one before `A`, just imagine the chain going back further.  It eventually has to end, since no Git repository has an infinite number of commits, and the graph is constrained.)
- However, branch names, like `master`, *preserve* commits.  If there is *no* name for a commit like `D` above, `D` is in danger of being cleaned up and removed by Git's *garbage collector*, as it seems to be useless.  So we add an external name to point to `D`:

  ```
  A <-B <-C <-D   <-- master
  ```

  Now Git knows that `D` is in use.  Since `D` points to `C`, Git knows that `C` is in use, and so on down through the history.
- The special name `HEAD` usually contains the *name of a branch*.  The branch name itself, such as `master`, has its usual role of identifying some specific commit (`D`) and thereby keeping `D` alive.  The name `HEAD` serves to tell Git which branch-name is to be treated as the *current* branch.
- When you make a new commit with `git commit`, Git uses the contents of the *index* to make the new commit.  The index, also called the staging area and sometimes the cache, sits "between" the current (HEAD) commit and the work-tree.  Hence every file for the current commit has (up to) *three* versions: the one in `HEAD`, the one in the index, and the one in the work-tree.

  You can copy files back and forth between index and work-tree, and you can copy files *out* of any commit into the index; but commits are read-only, so you cannot copy from the index into an existing commit.  You can only make a *new* commit from the index.
- The work-tree, of course, holds your files in the normal readable/writable fashion, rather than some special Gitty format (as used in the commits themselves and in the index).

What `git reset` does (in normal modes, `--soft`, `--mixed`, and `--hard`) is to do up to three jobs:

1. Change something (usually the current branch's stored hash ID) via `HEAD`.  It *always* does this, but if you use `HEAD` as the new value, the new value is the same as the old value, so nothing actually changes.  (Stop here if `--soft`.)
2. Re-set the index.  This part is optional: it only happens for `--mixed` and `--hard`.  (Stop here if `--mixed`.)  Resetting means *copy everything from the (now re-set) `HEAD` into the index.*
3. Re-set the work-tree.  This part is optional: it only happens for `--hard`.  Resetting means *copy everything from the (now re-set) index into the work-tree.*

Now, you mention you want to roll things back to the state they had during commit `A`.  Defining *things* correctly is the problem here.  We can make the *branch name* point to commit `A`:

```
A   <-- master (HEAD)
 \
  B--C--D
```

which is done with the first action, which always happens: `git reset <hash of A>` makes the current branch—presumably `master`—point to commit `A`, even if you use `--soft`.  Using `--mixed` or `--hard` will also re-set the index, or both index and work-tree.

This immediately un-protects `B`, `C`, and `D`, though.  So you should first protect them by adding a name (branch or tag) to remember `D`, which will protect it.  `D` will then protect `C`, which will protect `B`.

Meanwhile, what you have done here is to make a branch name "move backwards".  There's nothing inherently *wrong* with this, but other people and processes may not expect that to happen.  Normally branch names only "move forwards" (we add *new* commits and make the branch name point to the newest one, which lets us continue accessing the still-protected older commits).  So this *may* not be the right way to do this.  (If everyone else who is using this branch name agrees that it moves this way, it's fine.  If not, it's not.)

You mention `git cherry-pick`.  What `git cherry-pick` does is turn a commit *into* a change (commits themselves are full snapshots, saving whatever was in the index when you ran `git commit`).  It then tries to apply the change wherever you are now.  Suppose, for instance, that we do exactly the above `git reset --hard`, after making a new name `save` point to commit `D`:

```
A   <-- master (HEAD)
 \
  B--C--D   <-- save
```

You can now run `git cherry-pick <hash-of-C>` or `git cherry-pick save~1` (both of these will identify commit `C`).  Git will then compare the contents of commit `C` to the contents of commit `B`.  Whatever changed, Git will attempt to make those changes now to the contents of your index and work-tree.  If all that succeeds, Git will commit the result:

```
A--C'   <-- master (HEAD)
 \
  B--C--D   <-- save
```

Here, I call the new commit `C'` because it resembles `C` a lot: it makes the same *changes* as `C` (but to a different base!), and has the same *commit message* as `C` (usually with a "cherry-picked from ..." annotation added).

When you are done cherry-picking and have no use at all for commits `B` through `D`, you can simply delete the name that is keeping them around and easy to find.  At this point, those three commits really do (well, maybe<sup>1</sup>) become eligible to be taken out with the trash when `git gc` runs.

---

<sup>1</sup>Git tries *really hard* not to lose commits.  As a result, there are many ways that a commit *won't* be collected quickly, including "reflogs" and age.  A commit that is under 14 days old is never pruned by default; a commit that is in a reflog entry is also not pruned; and reflog entries themselves usually stick around for at least 30 days.  Deleting the `save` name throws out the reflog for `save` itself, but the reflogs for `HEAD` and `master` are likely to retain the commits for some time.

Comment: Thanks, that's very informative. Sounds like if I *just* do a `reset`, then that could cause problems for other users of the repo. What do you think about the method described here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1895059/revert-to-a-commit-by-a-sha-hash-in-git/1895095#1895095 Would this method avoid those problems? Would I still need to create a branch or tag to keep the intermediate commits from getting thrown out?

Comment: (Well ... who else uses the repo? Ideally, no one: your repo should be *yours*. Normally the more interesting question is, who else do you share the *branch name* with, via push and fetch and merge? The distinction here matters sometimes, so it's good to keep it in mind.) In any case, yes, Charles Bailey's method is fine, as long as you have reflogs enabled, which is the default.

Comment: +1 for such a thorough explanation.  The fact that this has to be so long and long-winded for such a simple answer is why I have a love/hate relationship with Git.

Comment: @mjuarez: Hence the old saying that Git makes more sense once you understand (fill in some blank), which itself simplifies to "Git makes more sense once you understand Git" :-)

Answer (score 3):

To quickly answer your questions:

> 1. Does git reset --hard remove anything from the commit history? If I reset the master to A, will B, C and D still be hanging around in the repo?

`git reset --hard` does not delete anything from your local repository. It moves your branch pointer around in preparation for your next commit. The commits that are not pointed to will be eventually deleted, but not immediately. You can read more about that topic in the docs for `git gc`

For example, after a `git reset --hard A`, you can immediately recover your "lost" commits with the command: `git merge --ff-only D`.

Personally, before I do a `git reset --hard`, I like to mark the 'current' commit with a tag: `git tag here` just so that after I get done playing with my history, I can easily determine if I have made the desired side effects by executing `git diff here..HEAD`

> 2. Does git cherry-pick allow me to do what I described above, or did I misunderstand it?

`git cherry-pick` does indeed do what you describe (selectively apply the patches)

Answer (score 0):

Just for information, because that's not your question, you'd better use `git rebase -i` than `git reset --hard`.

Then, during the rebase, you just have to delete the lines of the commits you don't want anymore.

Because after your reset, chances are that you won't see commit anymore and except if you wrote somewhere the sha1, you will have difficulties to cherrypick them (except if you have a look to the reflog).