# Git revert the pushed changes to previous commit

Tags: git

development and UAT.
Where development is a branch we develop and UAT is live server.

I had pushed some files from dev to UAT.

Now i want to revert the files(has errors) that are pushed to UAT to previous working copy of UAT .

How do i do this?

Im confused with below commands:

```
git reset --soft HEAD~1

git revert HEAD
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to undo the most recent commits in Git?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/927358/how-to-undo-the-most-recent-commits-in-git)

Comment: Reset moves labels. Revert adds a commit undoing changes.

Answer (score 2):

## Undo published commits with new commits

On the other hand, if you've published the work, you probably don't want to reset the branch, since that's effectively rewriting history. In that case, you could indeed revert the commits. With Git, revert has a very specific meaning: create a commit with the reverse patch to cancel it out. This way you don't rewrite any history.

```
# This will create three separate revert commits:
git revert a867b4af 25eee4ca 0766c053

# It also takes ranges. This will revert the last two commits:
git revert HEAD~2..HEAD

#Similarly, you can revert a range of commits using commit hashes:
git revert a867b4af..0766c053 

# Reverting a merge commit
git revert -m 1 <merge_commit_sha>

# To get just one, you could use `rebase -i` to squash them afterwards
# Or, you could do it manually (be sure to do this at top level of the repo)
# get your index and work tree into the desired state, without changing HEAD:
git checkout 0d1d7fc32 .

# Then commit. Be sure and write a good message describing what you just did
git commit
```

To revert to a previous commit, ignoring any changes:

```
git reset --hard HEAD
```

where HEAD is the last commit in your current branch.

```
# Resets index to former commit; replace '56e05fced' with your commit code
git reset 56e05fced 

# Moves pointer back to previous HEAD
git reset --soft HEAD@{1}

git commit -m "Revert to 56e05fced"

# Updates working copy to reflect the new commit
git reset --hard
```

[Credits](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1895059/revert-to-a-commit-by-a-sha-hash-in-git).